# lodash .filter an array with subarray for a field value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an array of many json records, which each array contains a subarray. I would like to go thru each array and each of its subarray. there is a field and if the subarray field contains a value like 0, it stops and return a true. basically, stop looping and return a true of the first incident of a 0 value for the code field.

Here is my array/subarray structure

```
[{id: 0, name: 'test0', mySubArray[{id:0, code: 0},{id:1, code: 1}, {id:2, code: 2} ] }
{id: 1, name: 'test1', mySubArray[{id:1, code: 1},{id:2, code: 2}, {id:3, code: 3} ] }
]
```

Currenty my code is

```
getExists() {
exist = this.rows.map(row => (this.doesValueExists(row.mySubArray)))

return exist
}
```

in my other method

```
doesValueExists(subArrray) {
 let result = _.filter(subArray, 'code', 0)

 return result
}
```

Using lodash, I tried something like this but it did not work

```js
const result = _.map(row, mySubArray => _.filter(mySubArray, 'code', 0))
```

I am not familiar with lodash, but is there a better way to do this instead of making two calls?

Thanks and appreciated

Comment: What do you expect the `getExists` method to return? An array or simply `true` or `false` Currently, `this.row.map` will return an array.

Comment: it does return an array but all the length value is 0 even though the subarray does contain a 0 value for code field.

Comment: Right, but in your description it should "stop looping and return a true", so what should it do? Return `true` or return an array with the first element that has the `0` in it?

Comment: Could you please provide what you expect the `result` to look like after it's done mapping through each item and sub array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method and loop trough each array and it's sub array until "code" is equal to 0. The end code could look like:

```
const result = values.some(item => item.mySubArray.some(subArray => subArray.code === 0));
```

"result" value will contain "true" if one of your sub array "code" value is 0.